# CPack / CMake: Different installation prefixes per CPACK_GENERATOR

Tags: cmake, cpack

How can I specify different installation prefixes for the different CPACK_GENERATORs?

For example:

- the DEB package should be installed to `/opt/project`
- the TGZ archive should consist only of the `project` directory

From the [documentation](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.2/module/CPack.html) I understood that I would have to use the `CPACK_PROJECT_CONFIG_FILE` variable. Using that, it should be possible to achieve the desired goal. However, it did not work for me.

This is my CPack configuration:

```
set(CPACK_GENERATOR "DEB;TGZ")
set(CPACK_PROJECT_CONFIG_FILE ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/package.linux.txt)
```

And this is my `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/package.linux.txt` file:

```
IF (CPACK_GENERATOR MATCHES "DEB")
    set(CPACK_NATIVE_INSTALL_DIRECTORY "/opt")
    set(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX "/opt")
    set(CPACK_PACKAGING_INSTALL_PREFIX "/opt")
    set(CPACK_INSTALL_DIRECTORY "/opt")
ELSEIF(CPACK_GENERATOR MATCHES "TGZ")
    set(CPACK_NATIVE_INSTALL_DIRECTORY "")
    set(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX "")
    set(CPACK_PACKAGING_INSTALL_PREFIX "")
    set(CPACK_INSTALL_DIRECTORY "")
ENDIF()
```

I have made sure that all files get parsed using `MESSAGE()` directives, but the prefix of my packages is always `/usr/local`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Finally, I found out what was wrong. I had the `CPACK_SET_DESTDIR` [flag](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/CPACK_SET_DESTDIR.html) set. This makes CPACK append usr/local to the directory containing the binaries of the compilation. After removing the corresponding `SET()` directive, everything worked like a charm.

For the record I will provide you with my minimal working example.

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2)
project(stripped-down C)

add_executable(main main.c)

install(TARGETS main
    RUNTIME DESTINATION bin
    )

set(CPACK_GENERATOR "DEB;TGZ")
set(CPACK_PROJECT_CONFIG_FILE ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/package.txt)

set(CPACK_PACKAGE_CONTACT "Some One <some.one@somewhere.com>")

include(CPack)
```

${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/package.txt:

```
IF (CPACK_GENERATOR MATCHES "DEB")
    set(CPACK_PACKAGING_INSTALL_PREFIX "/opt")
ELSEIF(CPACK_GENERATOR MATCHES "TGZ")
    set(CPACK_PACKAGING_INSTALL_PREFIX "")
ENDIF()
```